# Pivoting multiple columns in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, pivot

I have a C# list of object which I need to pivot and transform. But I am not sure how to get the desired result. The code below talks about structure, the data and the desired result. I know, I need to first group the data and then pivot it. But I am confused how to achieve it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Rev> revList = new List<Rev>();
        Rev r = new Rev { Id = 1, Name = "One", Rank = 1, Region = "Global", Revenue = 600 }; revList.Add(r);
        r = new Rev { Id = 1, Name = "One", Rank = 1, Region = "USA", Revenue = 100 }; revList.Add(r);
        r = new Rev { Id = 1, Name = "One", Rank = 1, Region = "Euro", Revenue = 200 }; revList.Add(r);
        r = new Rev { Id = 1, Name = "One", Rank = 1, Region = "APAC", Revenue = 300 }; revList.Add(r);

        r = new Rev { Id = 2, Name = "Two", Rank = 2, Region = "Global", Revenue = 500 }; revList.Add(r);
        r = new Rev { Id = 2, Name = "Two", Rank = 2, Region = "USA", Revenue = 100 }; revList.Add(r);
        r = new Rev { Id = 2, Name = "Two", Rank = 3, Region = "APAC", Revenue = 400 }; revList.Add(r);

        r = new Rev { Id = 3, Name = "Three", Rank = 2, Region = "Global", Revenue = 300 }; revList.Add(r);
        r = new Rev { Id = 3, Name = "Three", Rank = 2, Region = "USA", Revenue = 100 }; revList.Add(r);
        r = new Rev { Id = 3, Name = "Three", Rank = 3, Region = "Euro", Revenue = 200 }; revList.Add(r);

        //Should result in THIS IS THE HARD CODED RESULT WHICH TRANFORM FUNCTION SHOULD GENERATE
        List<RevExtended> resultList = new List<RevExtended>();
        RevExtended res = new RevExtended{Name = "One", Id = 1, APACRevenue = 300, ApacRank = 1, EuroRank = 1, EurpRevenue = 200, GlobalRank = 1, GlobalRevenue = 600, USARank = 1, USARevenue = 100};
        res = new RevExtended { Name = "Two", Id = 2, APACRevenue = 400, ApacRank = 3, GlobalRank = 2, GlobalRevenue = 500, USARank = 2, USARevenue = 100 };
        res = new RevExtended { Name = "Three", Id = 3, EuroRank = 3, EurpRevenue = 200, GlobalRank = 2, GlobalRevenue = 300, USARank = 2, USARevenue = 100 };
    }

    public List<RevExtended> Transform(List<Rev> revList)
    {
        List<RevExtended> resultList = new List<RevExtended>();

        var query = from rev in revList
                    group rev by rev.Id into revGroup


        return resultList;
    }
}

public class Rev
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? Revenue { get; set; }
    public int? Rank { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
}

public class RevExtended
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? GlobalRevenue { get; set; }
    public int? GlobalRank { get; set; }

    public int? USARevenue { get; set; }
    public int? USARank { get; set; }

    public int? EurpRevenue { get; set; }
    public int? EuroRank { get; set; }

    public int? APACRevenue { get; set; }
    public int? ApacRank { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach you could take:

```
var pivoted =
    from d in data
    group d by new { d.Id, d.Name } into region
    let g = region.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Region == "Global") ?? new Rev()
    let u = region.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Region == "USA") ?? new Rev()
    let e = region.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Region == "Euro") ?? new Rev()
    let a = region.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Region == "APAC") ?? new Rev()
    select new RevExtended
    {
        Id = region.Key.Id,
        Name = region.Key.Name,
        GlobalRevenue = g.Revenue,
        GlobalRank = g.Rank,
        UsaRevenue = u.Revenue,
        UsaRank = u.Rank,
        EuroRevenue = e.Revenue,
        EuroRank = e.Rank,
        ApacRevenue = a.Revenue,
        ApacRank = a.Rank,
    };
```

If you need `null` values in the absence of a region, you need to change the models to be able to support them.

```
public class RevExtended
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? GlobalRank { get; set; }
    public int? GlobalRevenue { get; set; }

    public int? UsaRank { get; set; }
    public int? UsaRevenue { get; set; }

    public int? EuroRank { get; set; }
    public int? EuroRevenue { get; set; }

    public int? ApacRank { get; set; }
    public int? ApacRevenue { get; set; }
}
```

```
var pivoted =
    from d in data
    group d by new { d.Id, d.Name } into region
    let g = region.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Region == "Global")
    let u = region.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Region == "USA")
    let e = region.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Region == "Euro")
    let a = region.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Region == "APAC")
    select new RevExtended
    {
        Id = region.Key.Id,
        Name = region.Key.Name,
        GlobalRevenue = g?.Revenue,
        GlobalRank = g?.Rank,
        UsaRevenue = u?.Revenue,
        UsaRank = u?.Rank,
        EuroRevenue = e?.Revenue,
        EuroRank = e?.Rank,
        ApacRevenue = a?.Revenue,
        ApacRank = a?.Rank,
    };
```

Comment: Thank you for quick help. This is great. When Rank or revenue is not available for any region, currently, its shown as 0, how can I set it as null?

Comment: @OpenStack Remove `?? new Rev()` from all `let` lines, and then inside the `select` use `g?.Revenue`, `g?.Rank` etc.

Answer (score 0):

**When you are not using C# 6.0**

```
var pivoted =
    from x in revList.ToLookup(d => new { d.Id, d.Name })
    let g = x.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Region == "Global") ?? new Rev()
    let u = x.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Region == "USA") ?? new Rev()
    let e = x.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Region == "Euro") ?? new Rev()
    let a = x.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Region == "APAC") ?? new Rev()
    select new RevExtended
    {
        Id = x.Key.Id,
        Name = x.Key.Name,
        GlobalRevenue = g.Revenue == null ? null : g.Revenue,
        GlobalRank = g.Rank == null ? null : g.Rank,
        USARevenue = u.Revenue == null ? null : u.Revenue,
        USARank = u.Rank == null ? null : u.Rank,
        EuroRevenue = e.Revenue == null ? null: e.Revenue,
        EuroRank = e.Rank == null ? null : e.Rank,
        ApacRevenue = a.Revenue == null ? null : a.Revenue,
        ApacRank = a.Rank == null ? null : a.Rank,
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

@OpenStack, you have an answer that is intended for users of C# prior to 6.0 based on the last portion of the accepted answer. You're example is not quite right. There are two issues:

- Your example will always have a Rev object so the object references
  will never be null.
- If you did allow nulls (as was intended), the assignment logic doesn't protect you from nulls.

Here's the equivalent of the accepted answer for C# versions earlier than 6.0:

```
var pivoted =
    from x in revList.ToLookup(d => new { d.Id, d.Name })
    let g = x.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Region == "Global") 
    let u = x.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Region == "USA")
    let e = x.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Region == "Euro")
    let a = x.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Region == "APAC")
    select new RevExtended
    {
        Id = x.Key.Id,
        Name = x.Key.Name,
        GlobalRevenue = g == null ? null : g.Revenue,
        GlobalRank = g == null ? null : g.Rank,
        USARevenue = u == null ? null : u.Revenue,
        USARank = u == null ? null : u.Rank,
        EuroRevenue = e == null ? null: e.Revenue,
        EuroRank = e == null ? null : e.Rank,
        ApacRevenue = a == null ? null : a.Revenue,
        ApacRank = a == null ? null : a.Rank,
    };
```

If you agree, you may update your answer so that it is correct (copy and paste mine if you like) and I will remove this one.